# Images as labels of barChart

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to create a BarChart on which images are the labels of each bar.

A Minimal example of what I'm trying to do:

```
image1 = Import["test1.png"];
image2 = Import["test2.png"];
image3 = Import["test3.png"];
BarChart[{0.4, 0.2, 0.8}, ChartLabels -> {image1, image2, image3}]
```

The problem is the position of the image on the label. The image is not resized to fit within the Bar width, and so it fills a great part of the plot.

Another problem is that the image is not centered: the bottom left corner of it is on the label's expected position, and not the center of it.

Any ideas how I can solve this?

EDIT:

as example of an image, wikipedia's picture of the day:

```
image1=image2=image3=Import["http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/Cabiria_1914_poster_restored.jpg/401px-Cabiria_1914_poster_restored.jpg"]
```

works for the problem in hands. (Thanks J.M. for pointing out)

Comment: Where might potential helpers obtain your nice PNGs?

Comment: Edited question with an example of importing (jpeg, PNG, is the same for the proposes of the question.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if this is satisfying but you can always manually resize:

```
BarChart[{0.4, 0.2, 0.8},
 ChartLabels ->
  (Image[#, ImageSize -> 40] & /@
    {image1, image2, image3})
]
```

[image]

Comment: strangely, the code you presented in my machine/version (Mac OS 10.6, mathematica 9) does not give the result you show. It shows the problem I was trying to solve, namely the image is not centered on the Label's "place holder", but the bottom left corner of it is.

Comment: @J.C.Leitão this is in version 7 on Windows 7.  Sorry, I don't think I'm going to be able to help. :-/

Comment: @J.C.Leitão: does `BarChart[{0.4, 0.2, 0.8}, 
 ChartLabels -> 
  Placed[(Image[#, ImageSize -> 40] & /@ {image1, image2, image3}), 
   Below]]` work? (you can play around with `Placed` to get other alignments)

Comment: @PinguinDirk: I played around, and so far only the answer below works. However, the positions are relative, which really screw the exporting feature.

Comment: @J.C.Leitão: well, I see that @cormullion posted just such answer. `Below` seems fine to me (Mac too) - didn't try to export though.

Answer (score 3):

Mr.Wizard's solution doesn't quite work for me on MacOSX/Mathematica9, but a slight tweak of his magic spell works:

```
BarChart[{0.4, 0.2, 0.8}, 
 ChartLabels -> Placed[{image1, image2, image3}, 
   {{0, 0}, {-0.5, 1}}, 
   (Image[#, ImageSize -> 50] &)]]
```

[image: chart]

Comment: Notice that -0.5 is arbitrary, and needs tweaking depending on the image size.